# How to automate Azure DevOps Kubernetes Service Connection to Cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops

To deploy services via Azure Devops to my kubernetes cluster, I need to create a Kubernetes Service Connection manually. I want to automate this by creating the service connection dynamically in Azure DevOps so I can delete and recreate the cluster and deployment. Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: where is your cluster located? are you using AKS?

Comment: On azure (AKS), I create it via Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

you can create the service endpoint using the [azure devops api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0), 
check this out for api detail

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335657/vsts-create-service-connection-via-api) might be related